# Buying pocket GPS?

Tags: gps, hardware-recommendations

It's my first time making this kind of choices, and I really don't know how to go with a choice or another.

I  basically know that it should have good ***durability*** , a good ***battery life*** and good ***coverage***.

What are other ***practical*** considerations I should be aware of ? And what about ***accuracy*** ?

I actually need to have a pocket GPS to pick points from the electrical network (the nodes are the electrical posts), all to create a cartography of 1/25000 scale. I should cover 500 points or so.

Comment: Can you make this question into a GIS question and not a GPS question - what do you want to do with the data? What GPS would be suitable for my GIS Software.

Comment: Good call, let me do that !